# How to put background color *behind* bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have an input appear when a button is clicked but then I want a background all the way around both the button and the input.  Currently, my markup renders like the following:

[image]

So when the click reason, I basically want the yellow (alert-warning) background around the Reason button and the input.  My markup looks like this:

```css
div.saveReason {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff3cd;
    border: solid 1px #ffeeba;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.saveReasonDetail {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary mr-2 SaveEdits">Save</a>
    <div class="saveReason"><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2 SaveReason">Reason</a></div>
    <a class="btn btn-link CancelEdits">Cancel</a>
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 saveReasonDetail">
        <div class="form-group viReason">
            <div class="validator-container">
                <textarea name="iReason" rows="4" id="iReason" class="form-control iReason"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problems are:

1) I don't want the border underneath the button...I want the border to only be no the 'outside' of the yellow.

2) I want the yellow background to extend just a bit outside of the reason button (without affecting the margins between the buttons already in place).

Is this possible?

**Update**: I got valid answers from Kareem Dabbeet and Chase Ingebritson.  Kareem was first marked as answer, but not being an expert in HTML, I'm thinking the comment Chase made about a 'same container' seems to be important.  Make sure to review his answer as well.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use [tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#tabs) or [pills](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#pills) instead of buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question:

Just edit `div.saveReasonDetail` position and make it `inherit`:

```
div.saveReasonDetail {
    position: inherit;
}
```

now edit border-bottom color for the `saveReason` to make it the same as 'saveReasonDetail' bg-color:

```
border-bottom-color: #FFF3CD
```

For the second question: To simiulate a m-2 between each button, you need to change margin-right on the save button to m-1 and add padding left/right with the same value for the reason button like this:

```
    .SaveEdits { 
      margin-right: 0 !important;
    }

    div.saveReason { 
        padding-left: 0.25rem;
        padding-right: 0.25rem;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

I colored "cancel" link to insure that margins are alright

Here is the final result

```css
div.main { 
    padding-top: 20px; 
}
div.saveReason {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff3cd;
    border: solid 1px #ffeeba;
    border-bottom-color: #fff3cd;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0.25rem;
    padding-right: 0.25rem;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.saveReasonDetail {
   position: inherit;
}

.SaveEdits { 
margin-right: 0 !important
}
.CancelEdits { 
background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main">
    <a class="btn btn-primary mr-1 SaveEdits">Save</a>
    <div class="saveReason"><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary SaveReason"">Reason</a></div>
    <a class="btn btn-link ml-1 CancelEdits">Cancel</a>
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 saveReasonDetail">
        <div class="form-group viReason">
            <div class="validator-container">
                <textarea name="iReason" rows="4" id="iReason" class="form-control iReason"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close.  a) The yellow does not extend above the button.  I'll try to figure that out.  b) The default solution increased the space between the first and second button. c) Putting z-index:-1 made it 'invisible' (in my entire page markup which is too much to include).  It is just a standard bootstrap 4 page (to my knowledge).  I inspected the div it was contained in and it had no z-index applied to it - so 'auto' was being applied.  Any ideas?  Or do you need more of my markup?  I know your snippet seems to work.

Comment: Have you seen the rendered result?

Comment: For a: i've just updated the answer. 
For b: remove `mr-2` from anchor with `SaveEdits` class.

Comment: i've updated post, added better solution for problem a

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you would probably want to put both the button element and the textfield element in the same container. Once they share a common parent, you can set the textfield's `position` to be `absolute` and it won't affect the position of the other buttons.

```css
div.main { padding-top: 20px; }
div.saveReason {
  background-color: #fff3cd;
  border: solid 1px #ffeeba;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.saveReason > .btn {
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}

div.saveReasonDetail {
  z-index: -1;
  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="main">
  <a class="btn btn-primary mr-2 SaveEdits">Save</a>
  <div class="saveReason">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2 SaveReason">Reason</a>
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 saveReasonDetail">
      <div class="form-group viReason">
        <div class="validator-container">
          <textarea name="iReason " rows="4 " id="iReason" class="form-control iReason"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-link CancelEdits">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Accidentally edited your post when I thought I was fixing first answer.

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I put a comment in the question about reviewing your answer and the comment about same container.  Did you still plan on removing the line under the button?  If so, is my assumption correct that this markup is more 'html correct'?

Comment: @Terry I've updated the snippet to fix the border issue. Regarding the HTML structure, in this case, it probably doesn't *really* matter whether the textfield is inside or outside of the buttton as there isn't any other functionality in the example. If you wanted to make the textfield expand from where the button is, it would probably be best to have it inside of the button container. If the field will always exists there without moving, it's probably fine to be outside of the button container. It's whatever is easiest/makes the most sense in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

**This is your solution**

```css
div.main { 
    padding-top: 20px; 
}
div.saveReason {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff3cd;
    border: solid 1px #ffeeba;
    border-bottom-color: #fff3cd;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.saveReasonDetail {
   position: inherit;
}

.SaveEdits { 
margin-right: 0 !important
}
.CancelEdits { 
background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="main">
    <a class="btn btn-primary mr-1 SaveEdits">Save</a>
    <div class="saveReason"><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary SaveReason"">Reason</a></div>
    <a class="btn btn-link ml-1 CancelEdits">Cancel</a>
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-2 saveReasonDetail">
        <div class="form-group viReason">
            <div class="validator-container">
                <textarea name="iReason" rows="4" id="iReason" class="form-control iReason"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```